# Android Virtual Device Keyboard bottom buttons disappeared

Tags: android

It's not the first time this has happen to me. For some reason that I have not yet figure out, the bottom buttons of the keyboard disappear, disabling me from closing the keyboard, even if I click outside.

[image]

In the space pointed by the arrow, usually we see this:

[image]

I'm using the VS Code and I dunno if I triggered any Hot Key by mistake.

- The bug is not related with the app I'm developing
- Restarting the device doesn't work
- Turning on / off the device doesn't work

The only thing that worked was deleting the device and creating another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not find out what triggered the problem but doing "Cold boot" works.

[image]

I can now see the buttons & they work.

[image]